# Any special meaning for @types?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have the following in a package.json file for npm

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^6.0.46",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.33"
},
```

Any special meaning for @ or @types ?

Answer (score 4):

That is a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

Scoped packages allow multiple developers to have packages with the same name as they exist in different unique namespaces based on the developer's unique username.